# REGEXP_REPLACE: replace all text following a pattern including linefeeds

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I am facing the following problem - I want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace the occurrences of all kind of symbols after a given string. Suppose I have the string:

```
I will send you the parcel today.
best regards (may contain multiple new lines)
Tom
```

I want to replace everything after 'best regards' with 'someone'
so that the output gets:

```
I will send you the parcel today.
best regards
someone
```

I tried with:

```
(best regards)[\w\W]*
```

but it doesn't seem to work and only best regards gets replaced. 
Since I thought that the problem was with the new line , I transformed the 
expression into:

```
(best regards)[\w\W|\r|\n|\f]*
```

but it still doesn't work.
I tried the expression using : https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html
and it did work.

The column is of type CLOB.

Comment: Could you tell me how to add it?

Comment: You may use a `.*` to match any chars as many as possible incl. a newline.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm. Everything is explained: *`'n'` allows the period (`.`), which is the match-any-character character, to match the newline character. If you omit this parameter, the period does not match the newline character.*

Comment: So, I have to write it like : REGEXP_REPLACE(input, '(best regards).*' ,'sOMEONE',1, 'n', 1)

Comment: See http://rextester.com/NFIH76859

Comment: Oracle and freeformatter use different regex engines. Do not rely on regex tools much if you are not sure if the regex engine they use is compatible with  yours.